# How to preallocate array in python for loop?

Tags: python-2.7, matlab, for-loop, image-processing, correlation

I am trying to convert the following Matlab code into Python code. I have converted more than 50% of the file but stuck at this point. In MATLAB:-

```
for kk=1:length(message_vector)
    pn_sequence_h=round(2*(rand(Mw/2,Nw/2)-0.5));
    pn_sequence_v=round(2*(rand(Mw/2,Nw/2)-0.5));
    correlation_h(kk)=corr2(cH1,pn_sequence_h);
    correlation_v(kk)=corr2(cV1,pn_sequence_v);
    correlation(kk)=(correlation_h(kk)+correlation_v(kk))/2;
end
```

In Python-

```
for kk in range(1,len(message)):
    pn_sequence_h = random.sample(range(1000,100000),k = int(math.ceil(Mc/2.0)) * int(math.ceil(Nc/2.0)))
    for i in range(len(pn_sequence_h)):
        pn_sequence_h[i] = round(2*(pn_sequence_h[i]*0.00001 - 0.5))*0.06
        correlation=[]
        correlation.append[kk]=corr2(cD,pn_sequence_h[i])
```

I want to change `correlation_h(kk)=corr2(cH1,pn_sequence_h);`line to Python which I alredy did but not working.

So I want to make a list in python which will save the values for each number. (`kk`). I am very new to python so I am so confuse. Pls, help.

Comment: outside of the outer loop, `correlation = [0]*len(message)` or some other sentinel value. Then just `correlation[kk] = ...` inside the loop.

Comment: Note that in your code snippet you are emptying the `correlation = []` variable each time through the loop rather than just appending to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the MATLAB code is doing is implicitly extending the matrix each time through the loop.  Or more specifically, it is creating a new matrix each time that is one element longer, then copying all the data from the old matrix to the new one, then deleting the old one.

Python doesn't let you do this, because it is slow and can be dangerous.  You need to create an array of the needed size initially (if you use numpy arrays), or you need to explicitly increase the size (if you are using a list).  Note that this is also slow and dangerous in MATLAB, so newer versions of the MATLAB editor with yell at you if you do something like this.

If you are adapting MATLAB code, you probably want to use numpy.  So here is the equivalent Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random
from scipy.signal import correlate2d

correlation_h = np.zeros(len(message_vector))
correlation_v = np.zeros(len(message_vector))
correlation = np.zeros(len(message_vector))
for kk in range(len(message_vector)):
    pn_sequence_h = np.round(2*(random([Mw//2, Nw//2])-0.5))
    pn_sequence_v = np.round(2*(random([Mw//2, Nw//2])-0.5))
    correlation_h[kk] = np.corrcoef(cH1, pn_sequence_h)
    correlation_v[kk] = np.corrcoef(cV1, pn_sequence_v)
    correlation[kk] = (correlation_h[kk]+correlation_v[kk])/2
```

However, you can simplify this by vectorizing the addition and using `numpy.random.uniform` to get random values between -1 and 1

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random

message_len = len(message_vector)
correlation_h = np.zeros(message_len)
correlation_v = np.zeros(message_len)
for kk in range(message_len):
    pn_seq_h, pn_seq_v = np.round(uniform(-1, 1, [2, Mw//2, Nw//2]))
    correlation_h[kk] = np.corrcoef(cH1, pn_seq_h)
    correlation_v[kk] = np.corrcoef(cV1, pn_seq_v)
correlation = (correlation_h+correlation_v)/2
```

However, this is almost certainly not what you actually want.  Try this is in MATLAB:

```
histogram(round(2*(rand(1,1000)-.5)))
```

You will see that the -1 and +1 values are less likely than the 0 value.  You almost certainly want a uniform distribution of random values, which you can get with this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

message_len = len(message_vector)
correlation_h = np.zeros(message_len)
correlation_v = np.zeros(message_len)
for kk in range(message_len):
    pn_seq_h, pn_seq_v = randint(-1, 2, [2, Mw//2, Nw//2])
    correlation_h[kk] = np.corrcoef(cH1, pn_seq_h)
    correlation_v[kk] = np.corrcoef(cV1, pn_seq_v)
correlation = (correlation_h+correlation_v)/2
```

If it doesn't result in too large of an array, you can even create all the random numbers at once, letting you simplify things a lot:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint


message_len = len(message_vector)
correlation_h = np.zeros(message_len)
correlation_v = np.zeros(message_len)
for kk in range(message_len):
pn_seqs = randint(-1, 2, [message_len, 2, Mw//2, Nw//2])
for kk, (pn_seq_h, pn_seq_v) in enumerate(pn_seqs):
    correlation_h[kk] = np.corrcoef(cH1, pn_seq_h)
    correlation_v[kk] = np.corrcoef(cV1, pn_seq_v)
correlation = (correlation_h+correlation_v)/2
```